# Inconsistent exception details in parallel stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, assertj

Most of the time, exceptions thrown in a parallel stream won't have all of its attributes.

Ex:

```java
@Test
public void test() {
    assertThatThrownBy(() -> Stream.of("1", "2", "asdf").parallel().forEach(Integer::parseInt))
            .asInstanceOf(InstanceOfAssertFactories.type(NumberFormatException.class))
            .extracting("detailMessage")
            .isEqualTo("For input string: \"asdf\"");
}
```

This fails most of the time, while this:

```java
@Test
public void test() {
    assertThatThrownBy(() -> Stream.of("1", "2", "asdf").forEach(Integer::parseInt))
            .asInstanceOf(InstanceOfAssertFactories.type(NumberFormatException.class))
            .extracting("detailMessage")
            .isEqualTo("For input string: \"asdf\"");
}
```

succeeds 100% of the time.

Another thing is when the message is absent, it will be present in the cause of the exception.
Ex:

```java
@Test
public void test() {
    assertThatThrownBy(() -> Stream.of("1", "2", "asdf").parallel().forEach(Integer::parseInt))
            .asInstanceOf(InstanceOfAssertFactories.type(NumberFormatException.class))
            .extracting("cause.detailMessage")
            .isEqualTo("For input string: \"asdf\"");
}
```

Any idea of how to make the parallel stream throw the exact and exception and not some sort of nested monster?

Comment: it crashes in a thread you're not handling so the error won't be detailed. it fails just as if it was inside a Runnable in another Thread

Comment: Not even the documentation of `Integer.parseInt` specifies a particular exception message format, so the fact that the message gets transformed during the parallel processing is irrelevant. Application code should not rely on a particular message format and since your unit tests are supposed to test your application code, there shouldn’t be any requirement to test the unspecified message format in your unit test either.

Comment: @Holger replace `.isEqualTo(...);` with `.isNotNull();` and you get the same result. The issue here is not the contents of the string, but the fact that it's completely empty.

Comment: The documentation doesn’t say that you can expect a non-null message either.

Comment: @Holger But as a consumer, wouldn't it be an *expectation* that such behavior remains *consistent*, even though not documented or guaranteed? (Relying on the OP stating it in occurrence as..*"most of the time"*)

Comment: @Naman it’s a subtype of `RuntimeException` which are usually considered to be a symptom of a programming error that must be fixed. For those, it’s already enough that a human programmer can identify the issue, regardless of whether the message is upfront or recorded in a cause. They are not meant to be processed automatically. For an automated test of the application logic, it’s already sufficient to know that an invalid input does not get through silently.

Answer (score 3):

Execution of parallel stream consists of a set of tasks that are divided among several threads, some of which come from a fork-join pool (typically the fork-join common pool), and also including the calling thread. The distribution of tasks to threads is non-deterministic, so a given task (like calling `parseInt` on "asdf") might be executed on some thread from a thread pool, or it might be executed on the calling thread. You don't have any control over which thread executes any given task. This particular task throws an exception, so the question is how exceptions are handled when they occur on the different threads.

If the task is executed (and the exception thrown) on the calling thread, the other tasks are canceled, and the exception is rethrown to the caller. If the task is executed on a thread pool thread, the exception is caught, the other tasks are canceled, and the exception is wrapped within a new exception (of the same type, if possible) which is then thrown from the calling thread. The code that implements this has a [comment](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/8ec1d42a9bad/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.java#l549) that describes what it does:

```
/**
 * Returns a rethrowable exception for the given task, if
 * available. To provide accurate stack traces, if the exception
 * was not thrown by the current thread, we try to create a new
 * exception of the same type as the one thrown, but with the
 * recorded exception as its cause. If there is no such
 * constructor, we instead try to use a no-arg constructor,
 * followed by initCause, to the same effect. If none of these
 * apply, or any fail due to other exceptions, we return the
 * recorded exception, which is still correct, although it may
 * contain a misleading stack trace.
 *
 * @return the exception, or null if none
 */
private Throwable getThrowableException() { ... }
```

The reason this wrapping is done is to preserve information about where the exception was caught, tracing back to the calling code. If the task that threw the exception is directly on the calling thread, the stack trace includes frames from the actual task execution all the way back to the caller. If the task that threw the exception is a thread pool thread, the stack trace for that exception terminates in the fork-join framework. The wrapped exception provides the additional frames that lead back to the caller. If the wrapping weren't done, the stack trace from a thread pool thread would be incomplete, and it might be quite difficult to determine the root cause of the exception.

Here's an example of a stack trace from an exception that occurred on the calling thread:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "asdf"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachTask.compute(ForEachOps.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:746)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.helpCC(ForkJoinPool.java:1115)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.externalHelpComplete(ForkJoinPool.java:1957)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.tryExternalHelp(ForkJoinTask.java:378)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.externalAwaitDone(ForkJoinTask.java:323)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doInvoke(ForkJoinTask.java:412)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.invoke(ForkJoinTask.java:736)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:159)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:233)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:661)
    at ParallelStreamExceptions.main(ParallelStreamExceptions.java:31)
```

And here's an example of a stack trace from an exception that occurred on a thread pool thread:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:603)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:678)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.invoke(ForkJoinTask.java:737)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:159)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:233)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:661)
    at ParallelStreamExceptions.main(ParallelStreamExceptions.java:31)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "asdf"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachTask.compute(ForEachOps.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:746)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:177)
```

Note that the only application code that's visible in these stack traces is the method `ParallelStreamExceptions.main`; the rest of it is library code. This is reasonably straightforward if the exception is on the calling thread. But consider if the original exception from a thread pool thread were simply rethrown in the calling thread, without wrapping. This could be "misleading", as the comment says, because it does not contain a stack frame from the application at all! Thus, wrapping the exception provides the missing context.

Now, what to do about the unit test? There are a few alternatives.

One is simply to check the exception type and not its detail message. In this example, checking for a `NumberFormatException` should work regardless of which thread throws the exception.

Two, if you really want to check the detail message, you can write a custom assertion for this. There's probably an idiomatic AssertJ way to write this, but the logic would be something like "assert that the caught exception is a NumberFormatException with the expected detail message, OR that the caught exception has a cause that is a NumberFormatException with the expected detail message."

Third, you might want to reconsider what you're testing here. The work being performed by the stream is the parsing of each stream element into an int. The example uses `Integer::parseInt` but I'll assume that this is a stand-in for some application code that performs some sophisticated work. The point of a unit test should be to test that application code against a variety of inputs, not to test the streams execution framework.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are receiving an exception that is wrapped by another type of exception that the `parallel()` throws with more information and the actual exception you are looking for is in `getCause()` or `getSupperessed()`.

The additional information the outer exception has may be the amount of items in the stream that through exception (e.g. "1 out of 3") or something of that sort.

Comment: Yes it is wrapped, hence the third example, but it shouldn't. The non-parallel stream exception is never wrapped.

Comment: @loeuf17 Are you sure it shouldn't? I'm not deeply familiar with parallel streams but is there somewhere a commitment to have exact same behavior as non parallel streams including the exception handling?

Comment: Maybe it should be wrapped, but, from my tests, it is not wrapped 100% of the time. Something like 70% of the time it is wrapped, while 30% it is not.

Comment: Maybe it uses both the thread you ran the command on and the thread pool and when the exception happen on your thread you receive the original exception but when it happens on a thread from the thread pool you receive a wrapped exception